# PDF not opening

Tags: java, pdf

I am invoking a pdf by using

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(pdffilename));
```

The pdf is opening fine in my machine in which I have Adobe Acrobat 9 pro installed. But its not opening in another machine which has Adobe Acrobat version 10.1.2 .

When I open the pdf it displays the error message

> java.io.IOException: Failed to open
>   file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/TheatreAudi t/data/AE%20wording.pdf.
>   Error message: Unspecified error
>
> ```
>     at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.ShellExecute(WDesktopPeer.java:59)
>     at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.open(WDesktopPeer.java:36)
>     at java.awt.Desktop.open(Desktop.java:254)
>     at uk.co.healthiq.MainFrame.linkAEActionPerformed(MainFrame.java:259)
>     at uk.co.healthiq.MainFrame$8.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:214)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
> ```

Could someone please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem is not with Adobe version. Can you put the file in a simpler location and recheck

Answer (score 1):

The path seems incorrect. Try introducing a variable for your file first, then check if that file exists:

```
File pdfFile = new File(pdffilename);
if (!pdfFile.exists()) {
    throw new IOException("...");
}
Desktop.getDesktop().open(pdfFile);
```

It seems to me you are passing something like "/C:/...". Try removing the first slash, and if that doesn't help try using windows like backslashes (remember you have to quote these in code).